# Pure-CSS - Hide text completely if it doesn't fit in div

Tags: html, css, overflow, pure-css

In my example there is a diagram, which has a horizontal bar that changes its width. The legend of that bar is shown inside but should only be visible as long as there is enough space to display the string completely.

I tried to adjust the parent container (bar, that changes width), so has the following properties:
**white-space**: nowrap;
**text-overflow**: ellipsis;
**overflow**: hidden;

Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/DerLukas/pen/VwvBbEN

In this example the string "BASE" should not be shown, because it does not fit in the white bar.

[example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlmFF.png)

```
<div id="modeChart">
  <div class="bar">
    <p class="label">BASE</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to apply those styles to the `<p>` that actually contains the text. Also you've got way too much `position: absolute` going on in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Still can't make it work, though. Can you show me a code pen, where it works?